# Как установить переменную окружения в Linux/Unix?

Tags: linux, unix

Как установить переменную окружения в Linux/Unix?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Необходимо открыть консоль и выполнить команду

```
export VAR_NAME=VAR_VALUE
```

Данная переменная будет существовать в рамках данного процесса и всех процессов порожденных данным. Для того чтобы данная переменная была видна во всех процессах, необходимо открыть файл конфигурации и добавить строчку

```
export VAR_NAME=VAR_VALUE
```

Если используется оболочка bash, то файл конфигурации будет .bashrc.

Answer (score 11):

Установить переменную только для текущей оболочки

```
VAR_NAME=VAR_VALUE
```

Для текущей оболочки и всех образуемых ею процессов:

```
export VAR_NAME=VAR_VALUE
```

Только для нового запускаемого процесса:

```
VAR_NAME=VAR_VALUE new_programm_to_launch
```

Answer (score 4):

```
sh, bash = export VAR=value

tsch, csh = setenv VAR value
```

Answer (score 3):

Во многих дистрибутивах есть `/etc/profile.d`, файлы из которой выполняются при инициализации shell'а, если переменные окружения связаны с каким-то приложением, лучше включить файл для `/etc/profile.d` с установкой переменных окружения в пакет приложения или создать его там вручную.