# Задать переменную в Linux

Tags: linux

Я не могу разобраться вот в чем. Утверждается что команда `source` эквивалентна `./`
Но это не совсем так.
Имеется файл `var`
В нем всего две строки:

```
#!/bin/bash
export PATH=/home/cj/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mips_r2_gcc-4.6-linaro_uClibc-0.9.33.2/bin:$PATH
```

Теперь я выполняю этот файл:
Сперва `./var`
Затем `source var`

И вот какой результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здесь четко видно что от `./var` переменные окружения не меняются.

А вот от `source var` переменная `PATH` поменялась и сохранилась.

То есть это не эквивалентные команды?

Какие еще способы есть изменить переменные для всего окружения?

Comment: export VAR_NAME=VAR_VALUE [Как установить переменную окружения в Linux/Unix?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/228/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-linux-unix)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Команда `source ./var.sh` эквивалентна команде `. ./var.sh` (обратите внимание, **точка пробел** перед `./var.sh`).

Comment: Теперь понял! Спасибо!