# Как правильно задать переменные окружения в Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu

Здравствуйте,я недавно стал осваивать данную ОС. Если в Windows было понятно, куда прописывать переменные окружения(для java, gradle и ant) то в Ubuntu у меня возникли трудности. В документации анта написано,что надо воспользоваться командой export, однако потом после завершения сеанса, эта переменная слетает. Я так понял, что дабы переменную прописать в env "насовсем" надо ее указать в неком bash. Но я толком не нашел пошаговой инструкции в сети(хотя может неправильно спрашивал гуггл) о том, какую команду написать, чтобы зайти в bash и прописать нужные переменные. Объясните пожалуйста как это сделать?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ls ~
```

Там увидишь либо .bashrc либо .bash_profile
Открыть для изменения

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

В конце файла вписать необходимое, например

```
export DEMO_ENV=success
```

Нажать ctrl+x затем y и enter
После выполнить

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: Чтобы вывести по умолчанию скрытые файлы, именование которых начинается с точки, стоит использовать команду `ls ~` с ключем `-a`, например так: `ls -a ~`

Answer (score 4):

Был ответ [вот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/228/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-linux-unix)

1. открываете файл /etc/environment
2. записываете нужные переменные:

   export VAR_NAME=VAR_VALUE

Comment: я видел тот ответ и если бы получилось,не задавал бы этот вопрос заново. вот я открываю терминал и пишу  ~/.bashrc, в ответ он пишет- "отказано в доступе"

Comment: файл environment можно какой-то командой в консоли открыть? а то я методом тракториста-зашел в папку etc нашел его, мышью перетащил в консоль и нажал enter. открылся текстовый документ, в котором одна строчка PATH=.....

Comment: @lga откройте файл с правами администратора.

Comment: я извиняюсь, но я совсем нуб( какой командой это сделать?

Comment: 1 открываем терминал. 2 вводим "sudo nano /etc/enviroment" 3. вводим необходимые переменные окружения. 4. Ctrl+O -> Enter Ctrl+X. 5 заходим снова и проверяем